# Python Merge two dictionary without losing the order

Tags: python, dictionary

- I have a dictionary containing `UUID` generated for documents like below.

```
{
  "UUID": [
    "b8f2904b-dafd-4be3-9615-96bac8e16c7f",
    "1240ad39-4815-480f-8cb2-43f802ba8d4e"
  ]
}
```

- And another dictionary as a nested one

```
{
  "R_Id": 304,
  "ContextKey": "Mr.Dave",
  "ConsolidationInformation": {
    "Input": [
      {
        "DocumentCode": "BS",
        "ObjectType": "Document",
        "InputContextKey": "Mr.Dave_HDFC.pdf2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358"
      },
      {
        "DocumentCode": "F16",
        "ObjectType": "Document",
        "InputContextKey": "Mr.Dave_F16.pdf2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

- I want to add the `UUID` by index to the `['ConsolidationInformation']['Input']` and inside individual `Input` as `DocumentUUID`, how can I map it using a for a loop. I tried searching on the internet but could not find a solution that could satisfy this nested condition.
- Expected output

```
{
  "R_Id": 304,
  "ContextKey": "Mr.Dave",
  "ConsolidationInformation": {
    "Input": [
      {
        "DocumentCode": "BS",
        "ObjectType": "Document",
        "InputContextKey": "Mr.Dave_HDFC.pdf2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
        "DocumentUUID": "b8f2904b-dafd-4be3-9615-96bac8e16c7f"
      },
      {
        "DocumentCode": "F16",
        "ObjectType": "Document",
        "InputContextKey": "Mr.Dave_F16.pdf2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
        "DocumentUUID": "1240ad39-4815-480f-8cb2-43f802ba8d4e"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

- I tried something like the below, but it resulted in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 26, in <module>
KeyError: 0
```

- Code

```
uuid = {
  "UUID": [
    "b8f2904b-dafd-4be3-9615-96bac8e16c7f",
    "1240ad39-4815-480f-8cb2-43f802ba8d4e"
  ]
}
document = {
  "R_Id": 304,
  "ContextKey": "Mr.Dave",
  "ConsolidationInformation": {
    "Input": [
      {
        "DocumentCode": "BS",
        "ObjectType": "Document",
        "InputContextKey": "Mr.Dave_HDFC.pdf2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358"
      },
      {
        "DocumentCode": "F16",
        "ObjectType": "Document",
        "InputContextKey": "Mr.Dave_F16.pdf2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358"
      }
    ]
  }
}
for i, document in enumerate(document):
    uuid = uuid[i]
    print(f"${uuid} for 1 {document}")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Issues**: You have done well with your attempt. The only issue is that the values must be accessed and added at the correct nesting level.

**Solution**: You can correct your attempt as follows:

```
for i, doc in enumerate(document['ConsolidationInformation']['Input']):
    doc['DocumentUUID'] = uuid['UUID'][i]
```

**Alternatively**: You can use the `zip` function. You can learn more about this function [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp).

Here is an example of how you may apply the function to your code:

```
for u, doc in zip(uuid['UUID'], document['ConsolidationInformation']['Input']):
    doc['DocumentUUID'] = u
```

**Output**: The output is as follows:

```
{
   "R_Id":304,
   "ContextKey":"Mr.Dave",
   "ConsolidationInformation":{
      "Input":[
         {
            "DocumentCode":"BS",
            "ObjectType":"Document",
            "InputContextKey":"Mr.Dave_HDFC.pdf2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
            "DocumentUUID":"b8f2904b-dafd-4be3-9615-96bac8e16c7f"
         },
         {
            "DocumentCode":"F16",
            "ObjectType":"Document",
            "InputContextKey":"Mr.Dave_F16.pdf2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358",
            "DocumentUUID":"1240ad39-4815-480f-8cb2-43f802ba8d4e"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go a little deeper in to your dictionaries;

```
for u,d in zip(uuid['UUID'], document['ConsolidationInformation']['Input']):
    d['UUID'] = u
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution that works using a for - enumerate without using any libraries. Please edit it to best suit your needs!

```
  "UUID": [
    "b8f2904b-dafd-4be3-9615-96bac8e16c7f",
    "1240ad39-4815-480f-8cb2-43f802ba8d4e"
  ]
}
Nested_Dict = {
  "R_Id": 304,
  "ContextKey": "Mr.Dave",
  "ConsolidationInformation": {
    "Input": [
      {
        "DocumentCode": "BS",
        "ObjectType": "Document",
        "InputContextKey": "Mr.Dave_HDFC.pdf2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358"
      },
      {
        "DocumentCode": "F16",
        "ObjectType": "Document",
        "InputContextKey": "Mr.Dave_F16.pdf2022-08-010T09:40:06.429358"
      }
    ]
  }
}

for a,i in enumerate(UUID_Dict['UUID']):
    Nested_Dict['ConsolidationInformation']['Input'][a]['DocumentUUID'] = i
print(Nested_Dict)
```